# Otimizar consultas com leftJoin Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Possuo tabelas vinculadas e quando necessito acessar as informações eu recrio a `query`:

```
DB::table('paciente AS pac')
      ->leftJoin('pessoa AS p', 'p.id', '=', 'pac.id_pessoa')
      ->select('p.nome, pac.ficha')
      ->where('pac.id', '=', $id_paciente)
      ->orderby('ag_prof.hora_inicial')
      ->get();
```

Como posso otimizar, para evitar a repetição desse trecho no `Controller`, devo criar na `model` ou em qual pasta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pode utilizar [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes) que é um método feito no seu `model` [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) para facilitar na programação, não seria uma otimização de banco, mas, sim um codificação limpa, ***exemplo***:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Paciente extends Model
{
    public function scopeJoinPessoa($query, $id_paciente)
    {
        return $query->leftJoin('pessoa', 'pessoa.id','=', 'paciente.id_pessoa')
                     ->select('pessoa.nome, paciente.ficha')
                     ->where('paciente.id', '=', $id_paciente);
    }
}
```

e utilizar no seu código assim:

```
Paciente::joinPessoa($id_paciente)->get();
```

***Observação:*** no seu exemplo tem um `orderBy`, que não existe essa relação, se por ventura esqueceu é só adicionar mais um `join` no método de `scopes`.

<sub>**Esse seria um forma de resolver esse problema.**</sub>

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)
- [Eloquent Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes)