# Relacionamento de Relacionamento Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um model chamado `Processo`, esse model tem uma relação **hasMany** com o model `Andamento`,  o model `Andamento` tem uma **queryScope** que uso para retornar os dados já com outras relações desse model, o que quero fazer é: através do relacionamento do `Processo` com o `Andamento`, também seja possível retornar as relações da **queryScope** do `Andamento`, isso é possível?

Código:

model **Processo.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Processo extends Model {

    function andamentos () {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Processos\Andamento');
    }

    function scopeInfo($query) {
        return $query->with('andamentos');
    }

}
```

model **Andamento.php**

```
namespace App\Processos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Andamento extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'processos_andamentos';
    protected $guarded = [];

    function scopeInfo ($query) {
      return $query->with('fase', 'tipo_andamento');
    }

    function processo () {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Processo');
    }

    function fase () {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Processos\Fase', 'id', 'fase_processo_id');
    }

    function tipo_andamento () {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Processos\TipoAndamento', 'id', 'tipo_andamento_id');
    }
}
```

A chamada seria algo como:

```
$Processo = Processo:Info()->whereId(1);

$andamentos_fases = $Processo->andamentos->fase
```

Comment: tenta assim, se der certo crio a resposta 
        return $this->hasMany('App\Processos\Andamento')->with('scopeInfo');

Comment: se não der tenta return $this->hasMany('App\Processos\Andamento')->with('fase', 'tipo_andamento');

Comment: Com o "scopeInfo" ele retorna: "Too few arguments to function App\Processos\Andamento::scopeInfo()", funcionou com o segundo comentário, mas é possível pegar o scopeInfo mesmo? para não precisar ficar renomeando a cada novo método

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***É*** possível da seguinte forma:

```
Processo::with(['andamentos.fase'])->get()
```

Ou seja, o nome das relações separados por ponto e se tiver outras adicione no `array`.

Se pode mudar seu `Model` para carregar todos as relações da seguinte forma:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Processo extends Model 
{
    function andamentos () 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Processos\Andamento');
    }

    function scopeInfo($query) 
    {
        return $query->with([
            'andamentos.fase', 
            'andamentos.tipo_andamento'
        ]);
    }
}
```

e

```
Processo::info()->where('id', 1)->get(); // ou first();
```

***Leitura:***

- [Para que serve um scope no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148776/para-que-serve-um-scope-no-laravel/151866#151866)
- [Como configurar um Anonymous Global Scopes no Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274713/como-configurar-um-anonymous-global-scopes-no-laravel/274721#274721)
- [Otimizar consultas com leftJoin Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207784/otimizar-consultas-com-leftjoin-laravel/208269#208269)

Comment: Funcionou, é possível usar já o scopeInfo do model Andamento nesse with?

Comment: @NBAYoungCode sim olha o exemplo na pergunta.

Comment: @NBAYoungCode se é a resposta da sua duvida marque por favor.

Comment: Não tem como usar diretamente o scope do Andamento? Ex: with('Andamento.scopeInfo');

Comment: @NBAYoungCode não uma coisa é carregar as relações, outra coisa é trabalhar com `Builder Query`, ou seja, são coisas diferentes.